# Extend native interface for element

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make a "semi-customized" button. Basically, I want it to extend the `<button>` tag's initial properties. Here's a minimal example of what I am doing:

```
export default class Button extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public render() {
    const { size, ...buttonProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <button
        {...buttonProps}
        className={classnames({
          [styles.small]: size === 'small',
          [styles.medium]: size === 'medium',
          [styles.large]: size === 'large',
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

However, what I can't figure out is how to create an interface which inherits all of the native HTMLButton's proptypes.

I imagine it would be something like:

```
interface Props extends <(Something)> {
  size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large',
}
```

How would you extend native HTML element properties in typescript?

Comment: Please accept my answer if your issue is completed :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HTMLProps` interface from react.

```
import { HTMLProps } from 'react'

interface Props extends HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
    size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces in TypeScript are open and multiple declarations within the same common root are merged. Example:

```
interface HTMLButtonElement {
    customThing(): string;
}

const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

const customValue = button.customThing();
```

The `HTMLButtonElement` interface needs to be declared in the same common root as the original interface (i.e. it is in the global scope). Once you add your `customThing`, your `HTMLButtonElement` will have all the members of the original `HTMLButtonElement` *and* your `customThing`.